# Open source CMS that can be plugged in on the back end of an existing site?

Tags: open-source, content-management-system, backend

I have a problem to solve which I think is relatively common. I have an existing web platform, built on a PHP or Java framework, which serves multiple sites. I would like to add a CMS back end to enable the company's employees to create, edit and publish content using an intuitive interface. However, I do not want the CMS to manage the front end of the site, I only want it to create the content in a database or XML repository, and hopefully deploy the content to multiple environments (preview, staging, production, etc). Our priority is a clean and stable editorial interface for non-technical users to edit and publish content.

I can then integrate the content with PHP or JSP templates on the front end, using something like mod_rewrite to identify content IDs in the URL and call content controllers to load the correct content from the repository. There should be no need to deploy any CMS code to the production servers at all. I've done this in the past using commercial CMSs such as InterWoven and Documentum, but now I'm looking for an open-source option.

I am looking at the usual list of candidates, including Drupal, Alfresco, WordPress, Joomla, and also more general frameworks like Django.

Would you recommend any of these tools (or any others I didn't list) for this scenario? Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

The list you're giving seems nice and diverse. I think you could add Hippo CMS (Apache licensed) to your list, since you don't mind a JAVA framework as your backend. It separates content repository from user interface and frontend applications by default and handles all the link rewriting for you in multiple websites and languages. Since Hippo is targeted at enterprise it works well in a DTAP (clustered) environment. For frontend templating you can use either jsp, freemarker, velocity or gsp.

You can try out the user interface here: http://www.onehippo.com/en/products/cms/try.
If you want to start developing, follow the Hippo trail on http://www.onehippo.org

Disclaimer: Hippo is my employer